# "it depends how" or "it depends on how"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is it needed to use the preposition on in the following sentence?

> The amount of cardio people do generally depends (**on**) how many calories they eat.

Answer (score 1):

Both "depends **how**" and "depends **on how**" can be valid - it depends what else you are saying. It also depends on dialect, but doesn't it always?

If "how" is taking its meaning in relation to method - "how you cook", "how you play baseball", "how you like your steak" - I would tend to find it more natural to say "depends how". "It depends how you prefer to eat crepes".

If "how" is followed by something like "much" or or "loud", I would tend to find it more natural to say "depends on how". If it is followed by a similar word referring to count, like 'many', I would find it more natural to leave out the 'on'.

I'm not sure I can say whether either is *wrong* in either case. I know that adding the 'on' to my examples without it doesn't seem wrong at all. Missing out the 'on' from your example feels wrong to me.

That said, calories are countable, so you don't want 'much', you want 'many'. If you make that change, it seems more natural without the 'on'.

Answer (score 1):

"depend" is a prepositional verb and is always followed by the preposition "on". Therefore, only:

- The amount of cardio people do generally depends **on** how many calories they eat.

is grammatically correct.

However, the form without "on" is acceptable in spoken English, mainly when the subject is short, as is the case with anaphoric "it" (referring to something mentioned before), for example:

A: How much cardio do people generally do?

B: Well, it depends how many calories they eat.

I don't think:

- The amount of cardio people do generally depends how many calories they eat.

is a good sentence even in spoken English.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct.

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/depend?q=depends)

> "Can you lift this case?" "It **depends how heavy** it is."
>
> How long the trip takes will **depend on how long** it takes to get through the traffic.